# jquery - both mouseout and click off?

Tags: jquery, mouseout

I have a drop down menu which is activated by click - no problem.
When you mouseout it closes - no problem.
I also want it to close when you click a menu item - PROBLEM.

When you click to close, it closes, but then as soon as you move the mouse it re-toggles the hidden class, presumably clashing with the mouseout.

I'm pretty new to jquery to please explain clearly.

The class 'visuallyhidden' is simply visibility: hidden.

```
$body.on('click', 'a.user', function(e){
      $('ul.user-links').toggleClass('visuallyhidden');
  });

  $body.on('click', 'ul.user-links', function(e){
      $('.user-links').toggleClass('visuallyhidden');
  });

  $body.on('mouseout', 'ul.user-links', function(e) {
      if($(e.toElement).parents('ul.user-links').length < 1) {
        $('ul.user-links').toggleClass('visuallyhidden');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm , I guess the problem is caused by the fact you're using `toggleClass()`; when you `click` the menu voice it actually `toggleClass()` , but when you `mouseout()` it `toggleClass()` again. Try applying a control on `mouseout` like

```
if($('ul.userl-links').hasClass('visuallyhidden')){
 ..
}
 else { }
```

using `addClass()` and `removeClass()` instead of `toggleClass()`
If you make a fiddle, I'll edit the question to answer better.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for the quick help.